# Problem with plotting products of polynomials

Tags: analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, desmos

First, I typed x(x-1)=0 in Desmos and they showed the correct two lines.
Then I changed the equation a bit into x(x-1)y=0 and they added a third line. But the previous two lines were *gone*.
Expanding the x(x-1)y on the left doesn't actually help.
Adding 1 to both sides (making it x(x-1)y+1=1 ) doesn't help, either.

What should I do?
Should I expect one line or three lines for x(x-1)y=0 ?
Is it a bug? I don't know how to report a bug.

Comment: I found a workaround using trigonometric functions, which helped me plot the rest of the soccer field.

Comment: My guess: Desmos automatically tries to solve expressions of $x$ and $y$ into a function of $y$. The line $y = 0$ is the only function of $x$ satisfying $x(x - 1)y = 0$, so it's no surprise. If you want to plot multiple lines, I would suggest plotting $x = 0$, $y = 0$, and $x = 1$ as separate equations.

Comment: [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yt9edpp2jr) is how someone else did it.

Comment: @TheoBendit Is it a bug? I don't know how to report a bug.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat I would probably not call it a bug. Instead, it's more of a compromise by design, so that Desmos can process semi-"natural" inputs. But, I don't work for Desmos, so what would I know? Telling them about this behaviour can't hurt.

Comment: @Scratch---Cat I found [this forum](https://cl.desmos.com/t/about-the-bug-reports-category/1254), which *wasn't* the place to point out bugs in the UI, but someone on the Desmos team responded to a bug report by saying "In the future, you can try support@desmos.com or open a ticket through https://support.desmos.com for more general support inquiries."